# A question regarding the number of papers that has a given number of references / citations

Tags: csv, reference, aps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeOR7.png)So I have a problem where in  I have to graph the number of papers that has a given number of  references/citations. But with the given information, how is it possible to do so?

[ Left - [Reference vs Citations
  Right- Citation information ]

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse your CSV using a library like [Papa.parse()](https://www.papaparse.com/)
2. Once you have your data in a JSON object, iterate through each entry and
   check the value of `CitedArticleID` against an object containing
   unique article names and the number of times each one appears.

   `{
    {"10.1103/PhysRevSeriesl.1.1": 6},
    {"10.1103/PhysRevSeriesl.128": 2},
    {"10.1103/PhysRevSeriesl.1.95": 1},
    {"10.1103/PhysRevSeriesl.1.166": 2},
    ...
   }`
3. If it doesn't appear on the list, add it to the list. If it does appear
       on the list, increment its count.
4. Once that's done, you can loop
           through the new object and find the articles with your specified
           count and then do what you've got to do with that info.

Comment: Hey could you help me out in this.I didnt quite get what you are suggesting.

Comment: Also for some reason the R version of Papa.parse is not available for 3.6.1.So please do let me know how I can get it

Comment: Sorry, I've got to go to sleep. If this question is still unanswered tomorrow, maybe I'll write an example in JS.